# CakePHP Pagination with find() and a complex query

Tags: cakephp, pagination, find

I've been hacking at this for a few hours now. Read about 7 or 8 online tutorials and I am still unable to get my pagination working with my search results.

Here are the basics of the situation:

In my plans_controller, I am call this in my search query function

```
        $this->set('plans', $this->Plan->find('all', $options));
```

The closest I came (which was not throwing SQL errors) by doing

```
$this->set('plans', $this->Plan->find('all', $options), $this->paginate());
```

**NOTE:** $options is the actual search query joins and conditions (and the query works perfect w/out pagination).

But the above did nothing to carry the search query to the following pages, and did NOT even work on the first results set from the search.

Using pagination for my needs seem very complex with CakePHP, but with this thread I am hoping for a more rounded explanation where I should start to get this going (and any other simple yet effective advice is welcome :)).

This is my first time trying at this type of complex pagination.

Here is all of my controller code. You'll see that much of it is inapplicable, but still trying to resolve this.:

```
var $name = 'Plans';

function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('search','index'); }

function search() {

    $this->Plan->recursive = 2;

    if(isset($this->data['Plan']['ApplicantAge'])) {
        $ApplicantAge = $this->data['Plan']['ApplicantAge'];
    } else {
        $ApplicantAge = 25;
    }
    if(isset($this->data['Plan']['SpouseAge'])) {
        $SpouseAge = $this->data['Plan']['SpouseAge'];
    } else {
        $SpouseAge = 0;
    }
    if(isset($this->data['Plan']['NumberChildren'])) {
        $NumberChildren = $this->data['Plan']['NumberChildren'];
    } else {
        $NumberChildren = 0;
    }
    if(isset($this->data['Plan']['Vision'])) {
        $Vision = $this->data['Plan']['Vision'];
    } else {
        $Vision = 0;
    }
    if(isset($this->data['Plan']['ZipCode'])) {
        $Zip = $this->data['Plan']['ZipCode'];
    } else {
        $Zip = 0;
    }

    $memberCount = 1; //We can assume the applicant is there
    if($SpouseAge > 0) { 
        $memberCount += 1;
    }
    if($NumberChildren > 0) { 
        $memberCount += $NumberChildren;
    }

    //2: Combo plan (1 adult + children, 1 adult + spouse + children)
    $comboType = 'sa';
    if($ApplicantAge < 18) { 

        //$comboType = 'sc';
    }
    if($SpouseAge > 0) {
        if($NumberChildren > 0) {
            $comboType = 'asc';
        } else {
            $comboType = 'as';
        }
    } else {
        if($NumberChildren > 0) {
            $comboType = 'ac';
        }
    }


        $options = array(
        'joins' => array (
            array( 
                'table' => 'plans_zips', 
                'alias' => 'PZips', 
                'type' => 'inner', 
                'foreignKey' => false, 
                'conditions'=> array('Plan.id = PZips.plan_id') 
            ),
            array( 
                'table' => 'zips', 
                'alias' => 'Zips', 
                'type' => 'inner', 
                'foreignKey' => false, 
                'conditions'=> array('Zips.id = PZips.zip_id') 
            )
        ),
        'conditions' => array(
            "AND" => array(
                array($ApplicantAge . ' BETWEEN Age.Min_Age AND Age.Max_age'),
                'Zips.title' => $Zip,
                'Applicant.amount' => array($comboType, $memberCount),
                'PlanDetail.active' => 1) 
        )
    );

    $queryStr = "SELECT Plan.* FROM plans AS Plan ";
    $queryStr = $queryStr . "INNER JOIN ages on age_id = ages.id ";
    $queryStr = $queryStr . "INNER JOIN applicants on applicant_id = applicants.id ";
    $queryStr = $queryStr . "WHERE (applicants.amount = '". $memberCount . "' OR applicants.amount = '" . $comboType . "')";
    $queryStr = $queryStr . " AND (". $ApplicantAge . " BETWEEN ages.Min_Age+0 AND ages.Max_Age+0) ";
    $queryStr = $queryStr . " AND Plan.id IN (SELECT plan_id FROM plans_zips where zip_id = (SELECT id FROM zips WHERE title = '". $Zip. "'))";
    //Add the vision limiting item
    if($Vision == 1) { 
        $queryStr = $queryStr . " AND dental_cost > 0";
        array_push($options['conditions'], "dental_cost > 0");
    }

    //$this->set('plans', $this->Plan->find('all', $options));

    $this->paginate = $options;
    $plans = $this->paginate();
    $this->set(compact('plans'));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

*Assuming* your `$options` variable contains a normal array of query parameters, all you need to do is **replace** the normal `find` call with a `paginate` call:

```
$options = array('conditions' => ...);

// normal find call
// $plans = $this->Plan->find('all', $options);

// same thing with pagination:
$this->paginate = $options;
$plans = $this->paginate();

$this->set(compact('plans'));
```

Comment: Hi Deceze, I'm not sure if you would consider my query (posted above) a "normal array". I would say it's not normal : ). I tried your suggestion, and it's not working properly. I am starting to look at this and thinking 1) It would be best to pass the parameters through the url, and then 2) keep the search parameters in the url so that when pages are paginated, the search stays through the pages. BUT I need to make sure the results are NEW as the pages are paginated Next >> for example.. This is ultra tricky!

Comment: @Old What struck me in your original code was simply that you were using `$this->paginate()` wrong. I can't really comment on whether or not the current code should work. Maybe you could clarify what the specific complications are?

Comment: I am probably making this more confusing that it needs to be. Basically, I am not sure how to approach this to get it working. I need to be able to paginate my search results limited to 5 records per page, and maintain the query as pages are changed (Prev or Next). The search data should also be unique to each page - in other words no duplicate results. This is what I am trying to achieve, but I just have no idea where to start or what the best approach is on this. Thanks for any extra advice : )

Comment: @Old I see now that your problem is probably that you're creating the query from POST values, which of course won't be maintained. You should change those into GET params, like `/find/SpouseAge:65/...`, which are then accessible via `$this->params['named']['SpouseAge']`. You can [feed those into the paginator in the view](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1233/Pagination-in-Views), so they'll be maintained. Alternatively: save those values in the session.